# why the two images are different? Are the functions same?

Tags: plotting, functions

why the second image just has the positive part? Is the problem in the domain of definition? 0.0

The code is here:

```
{Plot[1-Power[t^2, (3)^-1],{t,-1,1}],Plot[1-t^(2/3),{t,-1,1}]}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `CubeRoot` or `Surd` instead of `1/3`

Answer (score 11):

As others have pointed out alternative methods to get the desired result, I'll address the *why* of the matter.

The difference stems from a two-step cascade, the first being computational and the second, mathematical.  We can see the first step with the use of [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html).

```
Power[t^2, (3)^-1] /. t -> -0.5 // Trace
t^(2/3) /. t -> -0.5 // Trace
```

> {...,{(-0.5)^2, 0.25}, 0.25^(1/3), 0.629961}

> {..., (-0.5)^(2/3), -0.31498+0.545562 I}

These results show that the fundamental difference in evaluation is that the first procedure first computes the square which yields a positive number and is thus in the [principal branch](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrincipalBranch.html) of the following cube root, giving a real number which *Mathematica* can plot (as opposed to a non-real).  This is not the case with the direct evaluation in the second procedure.  The shortcomings of using `Power` are highlighted in the ["Possible Issues" documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0b8cspipuq-i88iix) of `CubeRoot`.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. It's really helpful! (/▽＼)

Answer (score 5):

```
{Plot[1 - Power[t^2, (3)^-1], {t, -1, 1}], 
 Plot[1 - Surd[t, 3]^2, {t, -1, 1}]}
```

Or

```
{Plot[1 - Power[t^2, (3)^-1], {t, -1, 1}], 
 Plot[1 - CubeRoot[t]^2, {t, -1, 1}]}
```

[image]